# Differencies in applying responsive web design among laptops and mobiles

Tags: android, html, css

Consider the following css code:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 768px) {
    ...
}
```

Could anyone explain to me why when shrinking the browser window in my laptop and make it exactly 768px large,only then the css properties(inside @media) are applied and not the same happens with my mobile which has a resolution of 1280x720 and a screen of 4,3 inches? To be more precise the above media query is applied to my mobile with the default horizontal resolution of 1280px while media query has  (max-width: 768px). Does it take into consideration some other criterion beyond resolution? If yes which? Maybe the actual screen size?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Smartphones have a different resolution in the browser, either 320px or 360px in width.

This is a standard so that websites can be read on such small displays.

Even though my smartphone has the display resolution of 1920x1080, the viewport is 360px.

[Here's](http://www.uxbooth.com/articles/considerations-for-mobile-design-part-2-dimensions/) a good read.

Comment: and what is the width of a nexus 4?

Comment: I can't find that anywhere, but it's either 320 or 360 for sure. If you have one, just add a 320px width div or image and see if there's any blank space on the horizontal.

Comment: I'm quite sure it's 384px. 768px width with a 200% px density

Comment: Yes, you're right and I think it's pretty bad that they started to fall apart from the standards.

Answer (score 1):

By default, mobile browsers use a viewport that differs from the phone's resolution. Your website will see the virtual resolution instead of the physical one.

If you want the virtual resolution to equal the physical one, use this HTML tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it has something to do with the pixel density. For example a Galaxy SIV has 1080px width with a pixel density of 300% that makes a screen width of 360px.

You have media queries that take into account the pixel density of the screen

http://screensiz.es/phone